# Repositioning background to make it look like a hand is writing?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, background-position

So I have this picture:
http://www.kyea.org/imageuploads/MC900382613.JPG
It's of a hand with a pencil and I'd like to position it on my web page so that it looks like it's writing the content. Is there a way to do this? I've tried messing around with background-origin, background-size, background-position, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following css est the image position .....

```
img {

position:relative;

float:right;

top:-15px;

left:-198px;

}

#text {

position:relative;

color:green;

text-align:left;

top:50px;

right:-90px;

}
```

for demo:[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NYLkB/)